# if there is no reduction from A to B

Tags: computability, reductions

I'm facing the following question :

> If there is no $\leq_$ reduction,
>
> does this necessarily mean that A is not decidable?

for any choice of B.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you define $B$ or how it is chosen? As stated above the question is incomplete

Comment: Narek, thanks for the quick answer.
in addition, it does not matter how B is chosen,
the question is - if there is no reduction from A to B, then is A decidable?

Comment: Actually it does matter, but do you probably mean for any choice of B?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant when said that it does not matter for this specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language $A$ is not necessarily undecidable if we allow any arbitrary but fixed choice of $B$. For example set $B$ to be the empty language. The only language reducible to $B$ is $B$ it self.

On the other hand, if you mean there is exists a language $B$ such that $A \leq_m B$, then for each language $A$ no matter if it is decidable or not there is such a $B$, namely choose $B$ to be the language $A$ it self.

Note that the only meaningful way to read the statement, is to fix $B$ to a language that is complete for the class of decidable languages. Clearly, decidable languages are closed under$\leq_m$ reductions, however, I don't think a complete language for this class is known (or whether such a language can be constructed). However, for such a language $B$, a language $A$ is decidable if and only if $A\leq_m B$ per definition of complete languages.

Comment: Narek,

thank you very much.
I really appreciate it.